# MYSQL insert same ID different explode on column

Tags: php, mysql, excel, explode

I need help making my script automatically sort out ids after a specific symbol from import documents, ughh, Let me explain.

I have an excel format document, which includes

```
ID____PRODUCT___________
1_____prod1*prod2*prod3_
2_____prod1*prod2*prod3_
3_____prod1*prod2*prod3_
```

So what I need to do is, insert them into mysql which would look like this

```
ID____PRODUCT____
1_____prod1______
1_____prod2______
1_____prod3______
2_____prod1______
2_____prod2______
2_____prod3______
3_____prod1______
3_____prod2______
3_____prod3______
```

so need to make so after every * it would make a new object from it, so far I have this script made, which does sort it to 2 columns, just need to make other column sort it with the same id. any ideas?

```
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $count++;                                     

        $expl=explode(";",$emapData[0]);    $string1 = $expl[0];    $string2 = $expl[1];

        if($count>1){                               
          $sql = "INSERT into products(a,b) values ('$string1','$string2')";
          mysql_query($sql);
        }                                          
    }
```

its a csv file, so its seperated with ; thats why I need to explode it.

So I just need to insert every product with new *, I could imagine use another explode to, but how do I assign it so it would insert it in a new column with same ID as the first one has?

Comment: You need to explode `$string2` by `*`, then loop through all values to insert, also stop using `mysql()` functions! Check out `mysqli/pdo`.

Comment: Yep, well thanks for tips and tricks, got it working, and Im only using mysql functions, cuz its only for private use, im only uploading a script, then using the functions once a year or something and thats it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 //connect using mysqli
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $count++;                                     

        $expl=explode(";",$emapData[0]);    
        $string1 = $expl[0];//ID like 1    
        $string2 = $expl[1];//the prod1*prod2*prod3
        $arr_of_products = explode("*",$string2);
        foreach ($arr_of_products as $value) {
            $sql = "INSERT into products(a,b) values ('$string1','$value')";
            //mysql_query($sql); do not use it
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Strawberry I just answered the question. the usage of whatever API is up to the user himself and he did not ask for advice on that. So I really don't see a reason for a downvote.

Comment: There are many answers here about the use of mysql_* functions. But after 10 years or so, we all stop answering these questions and **make** the OP update or use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Still no reason for a downvote imo. I changed my answer anyway

Comment: Ive seen this only after ive tryed out first comments tips, but yeh I did similar way of it, just a bit around, thanks for the help!